# Gatsby.js css: "undefined [undefined]"

Tags: postcss, gatsby

with the **gatsby-starter-default** build, running `gatbsy develop`, the build shows the following output:

```
src/layouts/index.css
undefined [undefined]

src/components/Footer/index.module.css
undefined [undefined]
```

What does this mean? The build seems to have succeeded. The only clue is that both these css files @import a `variables.css` file which uses custom css properties like  `:root { --blah-color: #ff3333; }`. So that seems to be the issue but what is the process that is failing / printing undefineds?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2462

quoting relevant bits:

> postcss-reporter version used by gatsby has a small issue where it
>   **prints out undefined [undefined]** for every @import ... in *.module.css
>   files

The printed message is annoying but harmless.